# ehcache -- hibernate many-to-many associations can't be loaded from cache?

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I have 2 entities

A  and B, related in a many-to-many relationship.

I set both to be lazy load, because in most cases I only need A, not the associated B.

I enabled ehcache. in a few cases, my code executes

```
A a = instance_of_ADao.getA();

for(B b : a.getBs() ) {
///
}
```

the first call getA() does lookup A from cache, but the second call (getBs() ) does not,
and instead generates a query:

```
SELECT * from A_B LEFT OUTER JOIN B on A_B.B_ID = B.B_ID WHERE A_B.A_ID = .....;
```

after this select, it does store the B object in cache.

I guess the reason is that the query in the second call is really pulling A_B, but I there is not a mapping for A_B (it's just a  in A's mapping), so I can't define that to use cache.

so is there a way I could utilize cache on the call A.getBs() ?

Thanks
Yang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the association itself to be cached.  If you are using annotations you can add the @Cache annotation on the Bs collection in A.